# When we burn a match stick it did not go at $c$ speed, why?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, everyday-life, mass-energy, combustion

When we burn a match stick then mass is converting into energy then according to the relativity match stick particles should go at speed of light but it did not happen why

Comment: Which particles? Light does move at the speed of light, and the carbon dioxide and water vapor are not only massive, but they also quickly ram into other stuff already there, distributing any excess energy they have far and wide.

Comment: “When we burn a match stick then mass is converting into energy..” No, the energy that comes from burning a match stick is conversion of bonding energy between certain organic molecules into thermal energy, which is very different than the conversion of rest mass into energy. ‘.. then according to relativity.. should go at speed of light..” Also simply not true.

Comment: @Bob Chemical binding energy does affect rest mass, but the energy is tiny compared to nuclear binding energy, so the effect is *very* small.

Comment: I guess you're trying to interpret $E = mc^2$. The speed of light appearing here doesn't mean that anything has to move at the speed of light. Also, the energy liberated in combustion is due to the rearrangements of atoms in different molecules with a lower potential energy. The mass of the match and that of the water, smoke and ash it turns into are practically equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should they?
Only massless particles travel at the speed of light.
When you light a match, the light that radiates does travel at the speed of light, and the chemical residues do not.